# Can I bypass Microsoft Family Safety when I use Tor?

Tags: anonymity

My employer is using Microsoft Family Safety to keep me from using Gmail (for example) and each time the computer starts I see a message saying that some sites are blocked and that the computer reports my activity.

I've noticed that I can access any site I want by surfing from Tor loaded on a flash drive in a USB port. So I can do anything I want, including checking emails etc.

Does my employer sees that I'm bypassing Microsoft Family Safety? If yes, can they see where I'm going?

Comment: Can your employer fire you for breach of company policy? Yes.

Comment: Indeed. Using Tor to circumvent the block goes far beyond inadvertent violation.

Comment: I have the option to actually bring my own laptop at work, maybe I should do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes, and no.  Yes you can bypass Microsoft Family Saftey when you use Tor. Your employer can find that you are using tor, but as for seeing what you are viewing the answer is no.  If your employer were to look at the packets being sent from the computer all that would be there to be seen would be of no use, as it would be garbled, seemingly random text because tor encrypts packets.

This all is assuming that your employer is not using any other means for witch to spy on their systems.  This could be anything from a keylogger (software or hardware) to a screen capturing software.

To see a similar example : https://www.theprivacyblog.com/anonymity/why-tor-failed-to-hide-the-bomb-hoaxer-at-harvard/